# Как сократить количество вычислений при поэлементном умножении многомерных массивов?

Tags: python, массивы, оптимизация, numpy, pytorch

Имеется трехмерный массив. Нужно перемножить между собой элементы последнего измерения.

Подробности и пояснения задачи в комментариях к коду:

```
matrix = tensor([[[0.4804, 0.8351, 0.2127],
                  [0.5993, 0.7906, 0.7307]],

                  [[0.0767, 0.2068, 0.2575],
                  [0.0811, 0.5181, 0.8339]]]) # исходный массив

first_elements_of_last_dimension = matrix[:, :, 0]

>>> tensor([[0.4804, 0.5993],
            [0.0767, 0.0811]]) # матрица первых элементов последнего измерения

second_elements_of_last_dimension = matrix[:, :, 1]

>>> tensor([[0.8351, 0.7906],
            [0.2068, 0.5181]]) # матрица вторых элементов последнего измерения

third_elements_of_last_dimension = matrix[:, :, 2]

>>> tensor([[0.2127, 0.7307],
            [0.2575, 0.8339]]) # матрица третьих элементов последнего измерения
mult_matr = first_elements_of_last_dimension * second_element_of_last_dimension * third_element_of_last_dimension # поэлементное (декартово) произведение

mult_matr
>>> tensor([[0.0853, 0.3462],
            [0.0041, 0.0350]])
```

Мое решение заключалось в итерировании по диапазону (*range* - количество элементов в последнем измерении) и перемножении единичного вектора на каждом шаге итерации (не самый быстрый способ):

```
product = 1
for i in range(matr.size()[2]):
    product *= matr[:,:,i]
```

Для того, чтобы сократить количество вычислений, нужно реализовать следующий алгоритм:
Умножить первые элементы матрицы на второй элементы матрицы, одновременно умножить последний на предпоследний. Повторять до тех пор пока не схлопнется.
То есть пусть у нас имеется 5 элементов последнего измерения `[0,1,2,3,4]`. Сначала `res1 = matr[:,:, 0] * matr[:,:,1]`, там же `res2 = matr[:,:,3] * matr[:,:,4]`. Потом `product = res1*res2*matr[:,:,2]`.

Можно ли как-то иначе сократить количество вычислений?

Comment: вам нужно сократить количество вычислений, или уменьшить время вычислений?

Comment: или всё одновременно?)

Comment: Все одновременно. В лучшем случае хотелось бы ограничиться методами библиотеки pytorch и избежать циклов. Самостоятельные поиски к результатам не привели.

Comment: я могу предложить ответ используя numpy, вам подойдёт?

Comment: Давайте конечно)
Я думаю в pytorch тоже самое будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [`torch.prod(input, dim, keepdim=False, dtype=None)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.prod.html):

```
In [5]: res = torch.prod(matrix, dim=2)

In [6]: res
Out[6]:
tensor([[0.0853, 0.3462],
        [0.0041, 0.0350]])
```

Если в результате нужен 3D тензор размерности `(2, 2, 1)`:

```
In [11]: res = torch.prod(matrix, dim=2, keepdim=True)

In [12]: res
Out[12]:
tensor([[[0.0853],
         [0.3462]],

        [[0.0041],
         [0.0350]]])
```

---

сравнение скорости выполнения:

```
In [21]: t = torch.rand(1000, 1000, 100)

In [22]: t.shape
Out[22]: torch.Size([1000, 1000, 100])

In [23]: %timeit make_task(t.numpy())
1.77 s ± 68.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [24]: %timeit torch.prod(t, dim=2)
20.7 ms ± 669 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

разница в скорости:

```
In [25]: 1.77 * 1000 / 20.7
Out[25]: 85.5072463768116
```

---

**UPD:** сравнение скорости выполнения `torch.prod()` - `GPU` vs `CPU`:

```
In [1]: import torch

In [2]: t = torch.rand(1000, 1000, 100)

In [3]: a = t.to("cuda")

In [4]: %timeit torch.prod(t, dim=2)
21.1 ms ± 275 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit torch.prod(a, dim=2)
2.44 ms ± 3.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: что на счёт скорости исполнения?

Comment: @Александр, по поводу скорости - надо тестировать, но я на 80% уверен, что для больших тензоров этот вариант будет работать быстрее - не надо конвертировать тензор в Numpy и обратно. А если доступен GPU, то numpy вообще будет "нервно курить в сторонке" ;)

Comment: ну ничего, есть ещё numba

Comment: @Александр, в Numba много ограничений - не вижу смысла перегонять тензоры в NDArray и обратно только для того чтобы воспользоваться Numba

Comment: @Александр, добавил сравнение по скорости... ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

# input array
arr = np.array([[[0.4804, 0.8351, 0.2127],
                  [0.5993, 0.7906, 0.7307]],

                  [[0.0767, 0.2068, 0.2575],
                  [0.0811, 0.5181, 0.8339]]])

# make product
def make_task(arr):
    return np.prod(np.split(arr, arr.shape[2], axis=2), axis=0)

print(timeit("make_task(arr)", number=10000, globals=globals()))
print(make_task(arr))

# output:
"""
0.9346408000000002
[[[0.08533142]
  [0.34621047]]

 [[0.00408435]
  [0.03503874]]]
"""
```

я уверен, что встроенные функции numpy будут работать быстрее вашего кода

я также нашёл некоторую информацию, как конвертировать numpy и torch:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/tensor_tutorial.html
надеюсь, поможет

поправка 1:

я сделал так, чтобы в конечном результате вместо

```
[[[0.08533142]
  [0.34621047]]

 [[0.00408435]
  [0.03503874]]]
```

было

```
[[0.08533142 0.34621047]
 [0.00408435 0.03503874]]
```

вот код:

```
# make product
def make_task(arr):
    product = np.prod(np.dsplit(arr, arr.shape[2]), axis=0)
    return np.reshape(product, product[:2])
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую сделать в pytorch.

Comment: успешно внедрили?

Comment: @Хачатур Саркисян, я дополнил ответ, посмотрите

Comment: Пока я с телефона. У компа буду вечером. Вечером или с утра отпишусь.

Comment: @MaxU красивое решение.

Comment: Сработало. Всем спасибо